# Could I avoid validation in ethereum smart contracts written in solidity for gas optimization?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

There are cases in which input validation is just to make sure users input is in the proper range , which if isn't would cause runtime errors .
Why should I bother validating that input and increase the computation cost for proper users (which are the majority)
Why shouldn't I just let the bad input cause a runtime error without me validating to prevent it from happening uninformed ?

and by validation I mean : require(),assert(),revert()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several reasons why you would want to use what you refer to as validation.  Below I have outlined some of them.

1) Ensuring your contract cannot get into an unexpected state.  Predicting how a user should interact with a contract is much easier than predicting how a contract can be misused so checks to avoid unexpected state help to limit code paths and the resulting attack vectors.

2) Debugging and giving feedback to the user.  If you have a problem in your contract code, using a require() allows you to give useful feedback to users of your contract(usually your front end code)

3) The cost of these operations is fairly small compared to the potential costs associated with misuse and/or re-entrancy.